# Can the formula developed by Olkin und Siotani (1964) also be used to compare correlations from Spearman's $\rho$ and Cramér's $V$

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho, cramers-v

The followgin formula is normally used for comparing two Pearsons $r$ correlations:

[image: Formula from Olkin und Siotani (1964)]

Can this formula also be used to compare correlations from Spearman's $\rho$ and Cramér's $V$?